# How to trace shortcode to its functionality

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to modify a plugin and I need to trace its shortcode to the functionality page(s).  Is there a way to parse a shortcode?

Comment: For your first question, `grep`. As to the second (about parsing a shortcode) it is not clear what you want. Please try to elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I always do is, I search the files...

So I use the "Search in files"-function in Notepad++ (which I am using) and limit the search to the directory, where I think, I will find what I am looking for.

So, probably, you know already the plugins directory. You enter this information into the folder input line e.g.:

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/plugin-with-sortcode/
```

When I am looking for a function I search

```
function NameOfFunction(
```

Shouldn't I find it, I try sometimes without the `function` part.

You are searching for a shortcode, you could try things like

```
add_shortcode( 'nameOfshortcode'
add_shortcode('nameOfshortcode'
add_shortcode( "nameOfshortcode"
```

You see, I alter the quotation marks as well as the spaces. If the first doesn't work maybe the second or the third spelling.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was great!  Thanks very much.  It does what I needed.